# Let $f:X \to Y$ and $g:Y \to X$ be continuous maps and $g \circ f= id$. Show that $f$ is an embedding.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> Let $f:X \to Y$ and $g:Y \to X$ be continuous maps and $g \circ f= id$. Show that $f$ is an embedding.

$f$ is an embedding if it's homeomorphic to it's image. We are to show that $f$ is continuous, injective and open/closed.

Continuity of $f$ is given to us so we will show it's injective. Suppose that $f(x)=f(y)$ for $x,y\in X$. Then $$g(f(x))=g(f(y))$$ but $g \circ f$ is the identity so $g(f(x))=g(f(y)) \iff x=y$ so $f$ is injective.

Now let $U$ be open in $X$, then $U= (g \circ f)^{-1}(O)=f^{-1}(g^{-1}(O))$ for some $O$ open in $Y$. Now $$f(f^{-1}(g^{-1}(O)))=g^{-1}(O)$$ but $g$ is continuous so $g^{-1}(O)$ is open in $f(X)$?

Comment: Yes I was editing the question still. I'm wondering if this is correct. The injectivity and openness of $f$ is a bit vague.

Comment: Since $gf=id$, $O=U$ isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$g \circ f = \text{id}_X$ indeed implies that $f$ is injective.

It's also clear that $f: X \to f[X]$ (now known to be a continuous bijection) is a *homeomorphism* by the existence of that same $g$ (which is a continuous inverse). No need to check openness etc.

Answer (score 0):

You write $U = (gf)^{-1}(O)$ for some open $O\subseteq Y$. Keep in mind that $gf:X\to X$. $g^{-1}(O)$ makes no sense for $O\subseteq Y$.

Write "..for some $O$ open in $X$." and "..so $g^{-1}(O)$ is open in $Y$", then your argument is correct. In fact, $O=U$.